# How can you separate waterline chaining methods

Tags: node.js, waterline

Let's say I have something like

```
User.find(options).paginate( {p:page, lim: lim} ).exec( //etc);
```

Is there a way to separate the chained queries in waterline? for example if I want to run .paginate only in a certain situation.

something like

```
User.find(options);
if (whatever) User.paginate( {p:page, lim: lim} );
User.exec();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

each function just returns a query, so you could do something like this:

```
var query = User.find(options)
if (whatever) query = query.paginate( {p:page, lim: lim} );
query.exec( /* callback */ )
```